# How to execute function after opening a jQueryUI Dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

On my web page i have some links like :

```
<div id="toolbarButtons">
    <a href="actualites/addLink" id="liens" rel="lien" title="Insérer un lien" class="toolbarButton"><span><img src="pub/struct/picto/icon_toolbar-link.gif" alt="Liens" />Lien</span></a>
    <a href="actualites/addImage" rel="image" title="Insérer une image" id="img" class="toolbarButton"><span><img src="pub/struct/picto/icon_toolbar-img.gif" alt="Liens" /> Image(s)</span></a>
</div>
<div id="dialogbox"></div>
```

First of all i init my dialogbox by calling :

```
initDialog : function() {
    $('#dialogbox').dialog({
        bgiframe:true,
        autoOpen:false,
        width:500,
        modal:true
    });
}
```

then i attach the the dialog on click event :

```
$('.toolbarButton').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            actu.dialogManager($(this));
});

dialogManager : function(elem) {

    elem.blur();
    var title   = elem.attr('title');
    var href    = elem.attr('href');
    var rel     = elem.attr('rel');

    $('#dialogbox').dialog('option','title',title);

    if(rel == 'lien')
    {
         $('#dialogbox').dialog('option','buttons',{
            'Add' : function(){
                            //TODO
            },
            'Cancel' : function(){
                $('#linkText').val('');
                $('#linkUrl').val('');
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });

        $('#dialogbox').load(href).dialog('open');

    }
}
```

As you can see , the content of the dialog box is fetched with ajax. The dialog contain some input.
I have a last function which is supposed to edit the content of the input but i don't know how and where to call it. It need to be called after the opening of the dialog to be efficient. How can i do that ?

doing it juste after

```
$('#dialogbox').load(href).dialog('open');
```

won't work because of the asynchronous loading (called before the dialog is fully loaded).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could do something when the dialog is opened.

```
initDialog : function() {
  $('#dialogbox').dialog({
      bgiframe:true,
      autoOpen:false,
      open: function() {
          // do something on load
       },
      width:500,
      modal:true
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you do something like this?

```
$('#dialogbox').load(href, function() {
   //your edit function?
   $(this).dialog('open');
   });
```

That function will be called when the load is completed.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: This is actually the right answer.. the heart of the question is that he wants to wait for the load to complete before executing a function, in order to do that, the load callback should be used as shown here.