# How to pass the return value of jquery dialogue box button function in some called function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to get the return value of jquery dialogue box, depends on return value true or false  of dialogue I need to call some other function , Here is my trial,but here it is returning [object object].

```
 function someFunction()
    {
      returnVal=$('#uploadMsrDialog').dialog('open');
      alert(returnVal);// RETURNING [object object]
      if(returnVal==true)
      {
        do some thing...
      }
    }
```

Here is my dialogue box open script :

```
  $(function() {
  $('button#btnAdmViewRej').click(function(){
  $('#uploadMsrDialog').dialog('open');
 });
$('#uploadMsrDialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 250,
    height: 200,
    position: 'top',
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
               "OK":function()
                 {
                    callback(true);
                 });
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                 },
                   "Close": function() {
                    callback(false);
                 $(this).dialog("close");
                }
    } //end of buttons:
    });

function callback(val)
{
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Instead of alert use console.log to explore the object - You will know by then if it is object or string. Note: The browser should be a latest version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute function after opening a jQueryUI Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144338/how-to-execute-function-after-opening-a-jqueryui-dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function someFunction()
{
  var returnVal=$('#uploadMsrDialog').dialog('open');
  /* 
  returnVal is a jquery wrapper object $('#uploadMsrDialog').
  At this point the dialog is shown and is waiting for
  the user to click OK or Close. The execution continues and 
  someFunction exits. callback function has not 
  executed yet. 
  */
}
```

The logic that depends on what user clicked (OK or Close) should be in `callback`:

```
function callback(val)
{
  if(val)
  {
    do some thing...
  }
}
```